# Jmeter - how to get the data of the latest selected value from the dropdown after login?

Tags: csv, jmeter

logged into the website by using the csv .By default particular customers data will be displayed on the page. Different customers would be present in the dropdown where the Admin has the access to select the customer and then the data of that particular customer would be displayed on the screen

Used blazemeter to generate the jmeter script where the default data response is generated all the time instead of the selected customer ID?

Kindly help me know how to pull the latest selected customer data In the jmeter and use that customer data in the consecutive steps?

Comment: Have you done correlation of the session ids? It's important before setting the dynamic customer ID. Can you provide a sample response with the customerID? We can extract the dynamic data from responses using JMeter Post-processors.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean you want to dynamically select customer and fetch data respective to the selective customer and want to use that data in the consecutive steps.

 For this

- First identify from which endpoints your frontend is receviving list of customers and their details.
- Once identified you will be having 2 endpoints
- 1st which provide all the list of customer/ or select is pre-rendred
- 2nd which provide detail for that customer
- Now extract data from 1st endpoint or HTML if pre-renderd save it in varaibe
- Now call the 2nd endpoint and extract the required data and save it in variable
- now the variable can be used in the consecutive requests

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't know anything about "dropdowns", it acts on [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) level so by default it will always execute the [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) which you have recorded.

So when you "select" the customer it generates some specific value for the HTTP Request, you can check the values for the different customers using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools), put them into a CSV file and replace the recorded hard-coded customer name or ID with the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the CSV file.

With regards to your question itself, the exact solution will depend on the dropdown implementation, it's hard to suggest anything meaningful without seeing the [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) code for the dropdown.

Here is an example of how you can get the last value for the [HTML Select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) dropdown using [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0/):

[image]